# Strange OpenCV issue with custom image format

Tags: c++, opencv, memory, compilation, ros

My problem is within the ROS framework, but I think it's actually an OpenCV issue.

My company has a custom image data type that we've used for many years. In ROS, I need to convert from an ImageConstPtr object to our image format. As a starting point, I used the ROS image transport subscription example on the ROS wiki. It builds and runs fine, i.e., the callback is correctly executed when it receives an image (in this case, using the *compressed* transport hint). However, if I declare a variable of my company's image datatype, which I will call Rgba, anywhere in the .cpp file - even if I don't actually use it anywhere - I get this when the callback fires:

```
[ERROR] [1387198570.300577803, 1386861997.933284812]: /tmp/buildd/ros-groovyopencv2-2.4.6-1precise-20131020-2316/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3346: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Strangely, I think this only happens when I subscribe to the compressed transport topic, though I need to re-verify that and I don't have a bag with raw or theora data in it.

EDIT: This code works fine (i.e., the output is repeated printouts of "Callback suceeded!"):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_WARN_STREAM("Callback succeeded!");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1, imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
}
```

This code gives the error above:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <custom_image.h> 

custom_image img_;  // This line causes the error displayed above. The callback never fires.

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_WARN_STREAM("Callback succeeded!");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
  image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("camera/image", 1, imageCallback);
  ros::spin();
}
```

What could be happening? My first thought is that we have some identically named class or structure that is interfering with OpenCV, or that our underlying image representation is incorrectly managing memory. What's strange is that the behavior occurs as soon as I declare the variable. If I declare it as a pointer, it doesn't occur, but as soon as I write a function that dereferences that pointer - again, *even if I don't call the function* - I get this error. As soon as I remove any references to our image type, the problem goes away.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it is because ROS tries to convert the image to a usual format, the one that is given to the cv_bridge. Is it possible? How do you get the ROS image?

Comment: Impossible to guess without some code

Comment: Interesting question. What's the actual code related to the error - "error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Our custom image data type has a libjpeg dependency, as does OpenCV. The versions are not the same, so when declare an image of the custom data type, the linker uses our version of libjpeg instead of OpenCV's, and we get the behavior described in the original question.